# Ionic (angularjs) ion-slide-box fails to render correctly from remote server

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project with angularjs which i'm trying to display some carousel images. What happens is when i test from localhost the images displays correctly but when i upload to the server and tries to get the images from the server the carousel appears destroys

JS

```
    $http.get('http://mywebserver.com/events/event_sliders.php?group_id='+$scope.group_id).success(function(data){
       $scope.slider=data;
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   });
}])
```

HTML

```
  <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" auto-play="true" does-continue="true">

            <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in slider">
                <div class="box blue">
                <img ng-src="http://mywebserver.com/events/{{item.img}}" class="banner" />
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
```

When i reference from localhost i get the display below
[image]

And where i reference from the server i get the display below

[image]

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you tried to empty browser cache incase you made changes in css?

Comment: that what happens on a real device too